# prevent Lumen from showing default 500 Internal Server Error on API responses

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I have a Route defined as:

```
$app->post('api/v1/Subject','SubjectController@createSubject');
```

And in the Controller I have the following code:

```
public function createSubject(Request $request){
    $Subject = Subject::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($Subject);
}
```

---

Now, when someone sends incorrect data, it triggers a Query Exception - "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:" which is understood.

However, what I want is: I want do not want Lumen to send its own default Error Page in API Response. **I want to capture this error event and send my own customized response.** How can I do that?

Since I could not find a solution, I tried to add my own view at: `/resources/views/errors/500.blade.php` but Lumen is even ignoring this template. Please help. Ideally, I would want to **capture this error** event and send my own customized response.

---

EDIT:

Lumen was reporting two exceptions - `PDOException` and `QueryException` at the 500 error response. So, to get a custom error message, I put the following code in side `function render()` in `app\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof PDOException){
        return response('It is my Custom response for PDOException that caused 500 error response.');
    }

    if($e instanceof QueryException){
        return response('It is my Custom response for QueryException that cuased 500 error response.');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: Checkout exception handler: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors

Comment: @vikingmaster So in ` app\Exceptions\Handler ` > ` function render ` > I wanted to add the following code:
`        if($e instanceof 500){
            return response('It is my Custom response for 500 Internal Server Error');
        } `

But I am not sure what is the class name for 500 error.

Comment: @vikingmaster I used PDOException and QueryException in the code above but it still it is not showing my custom error response.

Comment: Could you update your desc and show the code inside `render` method?

Comment: Can you show the response you are getting? Also, in the response that you are retuning in your `render` function, pass the response code `500` as the second attribute. By default it returns a 200 response code.